# Creating application using foursquare for business API

Tags: api, foursquare

I’m currently want to developing Application using foursquare. The brief description for this application is the user can check in toward a location then:

1. It gives a list of deals that offered in that place or (and)
2. it gives a list of top items or services that place offers

The question is, checkin is possible using the foursquare API however how about creating the business application for managing the deals and items ? Is it possible to achieve it with foursquare with business API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can help a business manage their presence on Foursquare through the [Merchant API](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/merchants). Once venue manages authenticate your application, you can create/manage specials and pageupdates, and get statistics about their venues their manage.